# How to pass a literal string value to the django url template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a URL conf such as this:

```
url(r'^value-toggle/(?P<profile_id>\d{1,10})/(?P<on_or_off>on|off)/$', 
                           'clipfo.profile.views.value_toggle',
                           name='value-toggle'),
```

In my template, I am trying to link to it:

```
<a href="{% url value-toggle profile_id=profile.id on_or_off='off' %}">Turn off</a>.
```

I get the following error when viewing the page which contains the url tag:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for
>   'value-toggle' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{'profile_id': 5, 'on_or_off': '### FIX ME - bad template
>   variable ###'}' not found.

Please note that "### FIX ME - bad template variable ###" is my `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` value.

How can i pass a literal "off" as the value of named param `on_or_off` to the `url` django template tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future has saved me!

Just called

```
{% load url from future %}
```

at the beginning of my template.

Using the url tag from future allowed me to do what I needed to do. I only had to wrap the name of the url in single quotes, such as:

```
<a href="{% url 'value-toggle' profile_id=profile.id on_or_off='off' %}">Turn off</a>.
```

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I thought the `url` template tag in Django 1.5 (the syntax `future` uses) just allowed the use of context variables as the first argument, which you're avoiding by quoting anyway.

Comment: load url from future isn't working for me... :/ still getting that "no reverse" error

Comment: Be mindful of quotes. One version of the url tag requires quotes around the page name, while the other requires no quotes. I do not remember of the top of my head which requires them, but try it both ways to see if it resolves your issue.